# populating form fields on select of dropdown from java beans

Tags: java, jsp, jstl, javabeans, el

i have an html form with 5 text fields.

i have an ArrayList of user objects created from a database query in a servlet.

i have populated a dropdown menu of selection choices using jstl and it populates fine.

```
<c:forEach var="user" items="${userList}">
<option>${user.userName}</option>
</c:forEach>
```

what i'm trying to do is isolate the user object from the array list on selection, and populate the form fields with other properties of the selected object such as:

user.firstName , user.lastName, user.email etc....

i have been searching for an answer most of the day with no luck.

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be handled easily enough in Javascript. The `<option>` tag has a `value` attribute where you can "store" data to be displayed. The `JSTL` would have delimited fields, e.g. using commas:

```
<select id="names" onchange="fillInFields()">
   <c:forEach var="user" items="${userList}">
      <option value="${user.firstName},${user.lastName},...">${user.userName}</option>
   </c:forEach>
</select>
```

The Javascript:

```
function fillInFields() {
   var fields = document.getElementById("names").value.split(",");
   document.getElementById("firstNameField").value = fields[0]; // name
   ...
}
```

For completeness, the fields:

```
<input id="firstNameField">
...
```

One word of caution with this approach is that this relies on no comma character `,` being present in the the selected fields. In that case another delimiter can be used.